# Fourier analysis an Introduction Chap 4. Exercise 5

Tags: equidistribution

5. Prove that the sequence {$\gamma_{n}$}$_{n=1}^{\infty},$ where $\gamma_{n}$ is the fractional part of 
   $$\bigl( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^{n},$$
   is not equidistributed in $[0,1].$

[Hint: Show that $U_{n}=\bigl( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^{n}+\bigl( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigr)^{n}$ is the solution of the difference equation $U_{r+1}=U_{r}+U_{r-1}$ with $U_{0}=2$ and $U_{1}=1.$ The $U_{n}$ satisfy the same difference equation as the Fibonacci numbers.]

I got the answer from this [site](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~d04221001/Notes/Problems%20and%20Solutions%20Section/Stein-Shakarchi%20Fourier%20Analysis/Stein-Shakarchi%20Fourier%20Analysis%20Solution%20Chapter%204%20Some%20Applications%20of%20Fourier%20Series.pdf) :

Proof. According to the hint, one observes that $U_{n}= W_{n}+\bar W_{n}$ satisfies $U_{r}=U_{r-1}+U_{r-2}$ for $r \ge 2$ and $U_{0}=2$ and $U_{1}=1.$ So $U_{n}\in \Bbb N$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z_{\ge 0}.$ Note that $\bar{W}_{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ since $\vert \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\vert<1.$ So we complete the proof since $\gamma_{n}\notin (\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})$ for all large $n$.

I can't understand why particularly $\gamma_{n}\notin (\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})$.

Comment: Because $U_n$ is a sequence of integers and $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\to 0$

Comment: $\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2$ is between $-1$ and $0$, so high powers of it are close to $0$

Comment: Is there a detail that shows $gamma_{n}\notin (1/4,3/4)$?

Comment: $\overline W_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ means for sufficiently large $n, |\overline W_n|<\frac14$

Comment: Who is the author of the book you mention ?

Comment: Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi

Answer (score 1):

$\overline W_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ means that, for sufficiently large $n, |\overline W_n|<\frac14.$

(In fact, that would be true for any positive $\epsilon$ in place of $\frac14.)$

If $|\overline W_n|=|U_n-W_n|<\frac14<1$ and $U_n$ is an integer, then

if $W_n>U_n$ then  $\gamma_n=W_n-U_n<\frac14$

and if $W_n\lt U_n$ then $\gamma_n=W_n+1-U_n=1-\overline W_n>\frac{3}4,$

so $\gamma_n \not\in(\frac14,\frac34)$.

Comment: It might be easier to see if you calculate $U_n$, $W_n$, and $\overline W_n$ for several values of $n$; you'll see that, as $n$ gets big, $\overline W_n$ gets very small (alternating sign for successive $n$) so $W_n$ gets very close to $U_n,$ so $\gamma_n$ gets very close to $0$ or $1$